# Change indexing of time in a dataframe

Tags: python, time-series, resampling

1. First issue:

I'm trying to change the frequency of samples from separate events to continuous range:

```
import pandas as pd
all_days= pd.period_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-08') 
df1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'2020-01-04': 2,  '2020-01-07': 10}, 'index')
df_new = df1.reindex(all_days, fill_value=0)
```

I get:

```
df_new
Out[571]: 
            0
2020-01-01  0
2020-01-02  0
2020-01-03  0
2020-01-04  0
2020-01-05  0
2020-01-06  0
2020-01-07  0
2020-01-08  0
```

But I want to get:

```
df_new
Out[571]: 
            0
2020-01-01  0
2020-01-02  0
2020-01-03  0
2020-01-04  2
2020-01-05  0
2020-01-06  0
2020-01-07  10
2020-01-08  0
```

2. More advanced issue: I want to perform the same thing with a dataframe, with several values for a date, such as:

   ```
    df2=pd.DataFrame([[10, 20],[6, 8],[2, 2]],['2020-01-04',  '2020-01-07',  '2020-01-07'],['A','B'])
   ```

For:

```
df_new = df2.reindex(all_days, fill_value=0)
```

I get an error:
**ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis**

But I want to get:

```
df_new
Out[571]: 
             A   B
2020-01-01   0   0
2020-01-02   0   0
2020-01-03   0   0
2020-01-04  10  20
2020-01-05   0   0
2020-01-06   0   0
2020-01-07   6   8
2020-01-07   2   2
2020-01-08   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to specify that the index is a DatetimeIndex.
Solution:

```
all_days= pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-08') 
df1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'2020-01-04': 2,  '2020-01-07': 10}, 'index')
df1.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1.index)
df_new = df1.reindex(all_days,enter code here fill_value=0)
```